# What sql engine is best in terms of low db size?

Tags: sql, sqlite, nosql

I have a script that gathers some data every 5 mins and stores it directly into a sqlite table using pandas to_sql function. So far it gathered around 300k rows and the table size already exceeds 30 MB for 5 columns. I intend to leave this running on a raspberry pi without external memory and was wondering if there's anyway to keep the size down, either by switching to mysql or possibly even using no-sql? What are your thoughts

Comment: 30 MB / 300k = 100 bytes. That means each row is using around 100 bytes. That doesn't sound too big to me. How do the columns look like? Just numbers, dates, short/long strings?

Comment: The columns are varchar I think since I don't create the schema or anything. They're cryptocurrency data, so numbers, a bit of text, a timestamp. I guess I don't know what sizes I am looking for, but felt that 300k rows would store way better than 30 MB.

Answer (score 1):

i think my sql, because  i use my sql have not problem unti now